# Clear a Status Notification Android

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

Im having difficulty clearing a status bar Notification.

```
public void NotificationStatus(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Stimulation.class);   
    NotificationManager notificationManager
        = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(
        david.flanagan.android.VenAssist.Activities.R.drawable.notification_icon,
        "VenAssist Stimulation ON", System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "VenAssist",
        "Stimulation Started", activity);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);     
}
```

I'm then trying to clear the notification status in the `onDestroy()` function of my service by calling

```
notification.cancel(0);
```

I have created an instance of the notification, which im not sure is correct.

```
private NotificationManager notification;
```

When I try to cancel the service, hence clear the status bar, the app crashes.

Comment: I suggest you paste the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notification object may be null, which would cause a `NullPointerException`.

I think you should be using a `NotificationManager` object to cancel a notification, use the same id (in your case, 0) and pass that to `NoticationManager.cancel(Int)`:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(0);
```

[NotificationManager docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29)